# If $L$ is a line bundle on a scheme such that $\chi(X,F \otimes L^{\otimes n})$ is a polynomial in $n$ for all coherent $F$... is $L$ ample?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $L$ is a line bundle on a scheme such that $\chi(X,F \otimes L^n)$ is a polynomial in $n$ for all coherent $F$... is $L$ ample? Or very ample?

The proof that $\chi(X, F \otimes L^{\otimes n})$ is a polynomial for $L$ very ample proceeds by embedding $X$ into $\mathbb{P}^n$ using $L$, then producing an effective Cartier divisor in the class of $L$ avoiding all of the associated points of $F$. This last step uses the embedding and the linear geometry of projective space.

I'm interested in knowing if the validity of this process is sufficient for (very) ampleness - not that this would be a practical criterion (unless only a small class of coherent sheaves needed to be checked), but it would be nice to know philosophically.

Comment: Well it's polynomial for $L = \mathcal{O}_X$. I don't know how to exclude stuff like that offhand.

Comment: @Hoot Oh good point ... I guess one could say, for $L$ non-trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, $\chi(F \otimes L^n)$ is polynomial in $n$ for any $L$. This follows easily from Riemann--Roch:
$$
\chi(F \otimes L^n) = \deg(ch(F)ch(L^n)td(X)),
$$
since $ch(L^n)$ is polynomial in $n$.